# Joining elements in a list without the join command

Tags: python, list, join

I need to join the elements in a list **without using the join command**, so if for example I have the list:

```
[12,4,15,11]
```

The output should be:

```
1241511
```

Here is my code so far:

```
def lists(list1):
    answer = 0
    h = len(list1)
    while list1 != []:
        answer = answer + list1[0] * 10 ** h
        h = h - 1
        list1.pop(0)
    print(answer)
```

But, in the end, the answer ends up being `125610` which is clearly wrong.

I think the logic is OK, but I can't find the problem?

Comment: I think the logic is flawed, you are always multiplying by 10. That will work only if the number has single digit

Comment: Is there a way to fix it so that numbers with more than 1 digit work?

Comment: Why don't you do string concatenation and finally convert it back to a number?

Comment: My guess is that that would be too close to `join()`, rather than a numerical solution.

Comment: Does it need to print that output, or return the number 1,241,511?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you just want to print the number rather than `return` an actual `int`:

```
>>> a = [12,4,15,11]
>>> print(*a, sep='')
1241511
```

Comment: Wow, I've never seen this :o Is this only on Python 3?

Comment: Yes, only on Python 3, with its convenient `print()`-as-a-function. :)

Comment: Or with `from __future__ import print_function` in 2.6+

Comment: Wow this works flawlessly...  But how does it work? Why the * before the list variable? What does "sep" command does?

Comment: @Twhite1195 Its called [unpacking argument list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments)

Comment: `sep` is the "separator" optional argument, specifying the string to be printed between each argument you pass to `print`. It defaults to a single space. There's also an optional argument `end`, specifying the string to be printed after the last argument. It defaults to a single linefeed.

Answer (score 3):

You could just convert each element to a `string`, add them, and then convert back to an `int`:

```
def lists(list1):
    answer=''
    for number in list1:
        answer+=str(number)
    print(int(answer))


lists([12,4,15,11])
```

---

```
>>> 
1241511
```

Answer (score 3):

```
s = ""
for x in map(str, x):
    s += x

print(s)
1241511
```

Comment: Though it works fine, don't use the same variable name for the iterator variable.

Comment: Try printing `x` after the loop

Answer (score 3):

There can be few more options like

### Option1

```
>>> lst=[12,4,15,11]
>>> str(lst).translate(None, '[,] ')
'1241511'
```

### Option 2

```
>>> join = lambda e: str(e[0]) + join(e[1:]) if e else ""
>>> join(lst)
'1241511'
```

### Option 3

```
>>> ("{}"*len(lst)).format(*lst)
'1241511'
```

### Option 4

```
>>> reduce(lambda a,b:a+b,map(str,lst))
'1241511'
```

Answer (score 1):

a numeric solution, using your code

```
import math

def numdig(n):
  #only positive numbers
  if n > 0:
    return int(math.log10(n))+1
  else:
    return 1

def lists(list1):
  answer = 0
  h = 0
  while list1 != []:
    answer = answer * 10 ** h + list1[0]
    list1.pop(0)
    if list1 != []:
      h = numdig(list1[0])
  print(answer)

lists([12,4,15,11])
```

Comment: You can actually do `answer = answer * 10 ** h + list1.pop(0)` and remove the next line.

Answer (score 1):

You may try `map` and `reduce` with `lambda` like this:

```
def without_join(alist):
  try:
    return int(reduce(lambda a,b: a + b, map(str, alist)))
  except ValueError, error:
    print error

  return None


print without_join([12,4,15,11])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an entirely numerical solution, playing off of your notion of messing with powers of 10. You were on the right track, but your implementation assumed all values were 1 digit long.

```
import math

def lists(list1):
    b = 0
    foo = 0
    for item in reversed(list1):
        b += item*(10**foo)
        foo += int(math.floor(math.log10(item))) + 1
    return b

a = [12, 4, 15, 11]
print lists(a)
```

This returns `1241511`, as requested.

All I'm doing here is looping through the list in reverse order and keeping track of how many digits to the left I need to shift each value. This allows integers with an arbitrary number of digits.

Answer (score -1):

```
list_name_of_program = [a,b,c,d,e,f]
program = ""            
for pro in list_name_of_program:
                program += str(pro)
                program += ","           # you can use seprator a space " " or different 
print(program[:-1])
```

## Output:

```
'a,b,c,d,e,f'
```

Comment: Hi Zeeshan Ahmad! Welcome to stackoverflow (well, I guess you've been lurking around for a while). While your answer technically does join the elements of a list without using join, there were already several answers which were correct, show a better understanding of the question as indicated by their repetition of the original poster's code themes, and had some description of why they answered the way they did. You may find it helpful to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer or other help articles at https://stackoverflow.com/help. Good luck!