# How to re-format a string (for a novice)

Tags: python, string, format

A quick question from a Python novice... the short version is : How do I re-format a string like ('A', 'B', 'C') into ABC?

Background: I'm writing a program that uses itertools.product to get all combinations of a set of letters *x* times. Eventually I want to search a much larger file to see how often each of those combinations occurs ([similar to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists-in-python)). So I need to ensure that the results from itertools.product are simply concatenated together, without the formatting characters and spaces. Each approach I've tried has failed or caused errors I don't know how to resolve. It seems like there'd be an easy way to do this...

Can anyone help me find a way to take strings like
('A', 'B', 'C')
and convert them to
ABC?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: What you mean by string like `('A', 'B', 'C')` ? is it a tuple of string or you mean `"('A', 'B', 'C')"`?

Comment: Do you just want to `print()` that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Joining elements in a list without the join command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29761800/joining-elements-in-a-list-without-the-join-command)

Answer (score 2):

Use a list comprehension within `join` function :

```
>>> s="('A', 'B', 'C')"
>>> ''.join([i for i in s if i.isalpha()])
'ABC'
```

Or use `ast.literal_eval` to convert your string to a tuple object then pass it to `join`:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> ''.join(literal_eval(s))
'ABC'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list, or tuple, just do this:

```
concatenated_string = ''.join(list_of_values)
```